# Infinite Monkey Theorem Python Comparison

Tags: python, performance, random, comparative-review, complexity

I wrote code to demonstrate the Infinite Monkey Theorem which states that if a monkey types at a keyboard for an infinite amount of time it will almost surely type a given text such as William Shakespeare. Here I've replaced the monkey with Python code. I have a sentence and let Python choose from the 26 letters of the alphabet and a space and have it randomly try to generate the chosen sentence.

```
import string
import random

def genString():
    letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase + " ")
    testList = [random.choice(letters) for letter in letters]
    testString = ''.join(testList)
    return testString

def score(n):
    score = 0
    test = "methinksit is like a weasel"
    if test == n:
        score = 100
    else:
        for letter in range(len(test)):
            if test[letter] == n[letter]:
                score = 1/27 + score
            else:
                score = 0/27 + score
    score = score * 100
    return score

def test():
    count = 0
    localScore = 0
    n = genString()
    guessString = ""
    while(localScore != 100):
        if score(n) > localScore:
            localScore = score(n)
            guessString = n
        if count%1000 == 0:
            print(localScore)
            print(guessString)
            print(count)
        n = genString()
        count = count + 1
```

However, for the test function I had a previous version which was:

```
def test2():
    count = 0
    localScore = 0
    n = genString()
    guessString = ""
    testList = [score(n)]
    while(100 not in testList):
        if max(testList) > localScore:
            localScore = max(testList)
            guessString = n
        if count%1000 == 0:
            print(localScore)
            print(guessString)
            print(count)
        n = genString()
        testList.append(score(n))
        count = count + 1
```

However, after testing it out I realized it was super slow. I'm guessing that the problem is that test2 has a runtime of O(n<sup>2</sup>) because of the loop and the `max` function and my previous test has a runtime of O(n). Is this true? Or is there another reason why it's super slow?

Comment: `max` is an issue, so is `in` both of which are `O(n)`. Also, the `append` is only amortized `O(1)` not `O(1)` in general.

Answer (score 2):

## Python naming conventions

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says that functions and variables should use `snake_case` so `getString` should be `get_string`.

## Naming issues

`localScore` is the best score that you have for all the generations, name it `best_score` instead. Similarly: `guessString -> best_string`. I think `count` is ok. I would have used `gen` or `generation` but then again it's not really a genetic algorithm so there isn't really evolution so one could argue `count` is better than `gen`...

## `gen_string`

I would say that it is pretty lucky that `letter` and `"methinksit is like a weasel"` have the same length. Give `gen_string` a length parameter. You don't need to convert `letters` to a list, and you don't need so many temporary variables. (I also prefer `keyboard` to `letters` since `" "` isn't a letter). Ultimately I came up with:

```
def genString(length):
    keyboard = string.ascii_lowercase + " "
    return ''.join((random.choice(keyboard) for _ in range(length)))
```

## `test`

Keep your `test` information in `test` and don't let it leak out.

```
test = "methinksit is like a weasel"
```

Should be somewhere in your `test` function, not score. Pass a `ref`erence string to `score`.

I would advise printing out more information than just numbers, something like this, so you can tell what is going on:

```
        print("Iteration: " + str(count))
        print("Best score: " + str(best_score))
        print("Best strint: " + best_string)
```

## `score`

This:

```
        else:
            score = 0/27 + score
```

Is unneeded. Just get rid of it. I believe also:

```
if test == n:
    score = 100
```

Is unneeded. (Although, there might be some weird floating point thing I'm not taking into consideration. Regardless, you can adjust for this.)

Don't have:

```
1/27
```

What should be in place of `27`?

`n` is often assumed to be an integer, yet you use it as a string.

## Organization

`test` doesn't really feel like a test, it feels like the main point of your application. Maybe just change it to `main()` and do something like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you think it is a test maybe move it into a testing file like `test.py`.